# newrelic/apollo-server-plugin with NEST.JS

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, newrelic

I am using NEST.JS framework and want to add [external](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/plugins#using-external-plugins) plugin New Relic Apollo Server [plugin](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-node-apollo-server-plugin/blob/main/README.md).

```
apollo-server-fastify: "^2.19.2"
@newrelic/apollo-server-plugin: "^0.1.2"

import { apolloServerNewRelicPlugin } from '@newrelic/apollo-server-plugin';

GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  ....
  plugins: [apolloServerNewRelicPlugin],
}),
```

1. When I start server for e2e test it required real NewRelic key ; is there a way to start for test environment without requiring real key ?
2. To test out things I started server with real key; Missing Key and cannot start agent error disappeared but below is the error I am seeing

```
     UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '__internal_plugin_id__' in undefined
    my-application    |     at Object.pluginIsInternal (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apollo-server-fastify/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/plugin/internalPlugin.js:5:37)
```

Comment: What version of nodejs are you using?

Comment: Node version 12.18

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** the plugin has been updated and it supports TypeScript now.

I've had the same error initially. The way I made it work here was to create a `typings/newrelic-apollo-server-plugin/index.ts` file containing a module declaration:

```js
declare module '@newrelic/apollo-server-plugin'
```

Then, in my NestJS module file:

```js
import apolloServerNewRelicPlugin from '@newrelic/apollo-server-plugin'

@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      ...
      plugins: [apolloServerNewRelicPlugin],
    }),
```